# Create new column that takes the sum of another column values and group by condition in R

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I would like to add a new column that is titled "pop sum" which takes the sum of all rows that has population data and is grouped by location. I tried group_by with Building and then sum = sum(pop) but that did work. I will just show one building but there are 30+ UNIQUE buildings Reference dataframe below:

```
`Date Ran`           Year Month      Building   Population MonthN
  <dttm>              <dbl> <chr>        <fct>       <num>    <chr> 
1 2018-09-28 00:00:00  2018 September     ALEX       1196    Sep   
2 2018-08-30 00:00:00  2018 August        ALEX       1172    Aug   
3 2018-07-19 00:00:00  2018 July          ALEX       1171    Jul   
4 2018-06-30 00:00:00  2018 June          ALEX       1167    Jun   
5 2018-05-11 00:00:00  2018 May           ALEX       1154    May   
6 2018-04-09 00:00:00  2018 April         ALEX       1154    Apr
```

Desired output would like something like this:

```
`Date Ran`           Year Month      Building   Population   MonthN  Pop Sum
  <dttm>              <dbl> <chr>         <fct>      <dbl>     <chr>      <num>
1 2018-09-28 00:00:00  2018 September     ALEX       1196       Sep        7014
2 2018-08-30 00:00:00  2018 August        ALEX       1172       Aug        7014
3 2018-07-19 00:00:00  2018 July          ALEX       1171       Jul        7014
4 2018-06-30 00:00:00  2018 June          ALEX       1167       Jun        7014
5 2018-05-11 00:00:00  2018 May           ALEX       1154       May        7014
6 2018-04-09 00:00:00  2018 April         ALEX       1154       Apr        7014
```

A function or for loop would be great but if there are any R packages I could load in to generate new column that would be great

Comment: `group_by(Building) %>% summarize(pop_sum = sum(Population))` should work, can you share your code?

Comment: What exactly do you mean the group_by/sum "didn't work"? Did you use `dplyr`? Did you use a `summarize()` or `mutate()`? I would have thought the latter should have worked just fine. When asking for help please share your data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that makes it easy to copy/paste data into R (this is not easy with your current data). Also, try including data with more than one Building to make sure we properly test the grouping.

Comment: My apologizes - I will change the question format. I used the dplyr but gave the sum of all the population total - not seperated by building.

Comment: @Dinho Are you sure you used a `group_by`? What you describe doesn't make sense. Please show your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `dplyr`, you usually are using summary functions to get another output. However, with group and ungroup, you can add a summary column.

```
 newdf <- df %>% 
    group_by(Building) %>% 
    mutate(PopSum = sum(Population, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with `data.table`

data:

```
library(data.table)

data <- data.table(building = c("Alex", "Alex", "Mike"),
               population = c(1312, 3123, 2139),
               location = c("Denver", "Arizona", "Detroit"))

   building population location
1:     Alex       1312   Denver
2:     Alex       3123  Arizona
3:     Mike       2139  Detroit
```

code:

```
data[, popsum := sum(population), by = building][]

   building population location popsum
1:     Alex       1312   Denver   4435
2:     Alex       3123  Arizona   4435
3:     Mike       2139  Detroit   2139
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly it and then some!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution using `ave`, maybe you can have a try with it

```
df <- within(df,PopSum <- ave(Population,Building,FUN = sum))
```